# How to implement custom key Map in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I got the following `Map` in `scala` and want to perform a pattern matching on the `Map`. For some reason it return the given error. I probably have to implement some kind of ordering for the `case objects`? How do I implement a `Map` with custom key objects?

```scala
sealed trait Status
case object Open extends Status
case object Processing extends Status
case object Completed extends Status

val map = Map(
    Open -> "open",
    Processing -> "processing",
    Meeting -> "meeting",
    MissingInformation -> "missing_information",
    Completed -> "completed"
  )
  
map(Open)
```

```
type mismatch;
found   : o.type (with underlying type example.Status)
required: Product with Serializable with example.Status
```

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Z76r2mxXTe6pNJBx2Y6Qbg

Comment: This should compile. Is this all of your code?

Comment: Okay for some reason it does not work on my code base. I will investigate and report later. Thank you sir.

Comment: Could you please try to specify the type of `map`? Also, which version of scala are you using?

`val map: Map[Status, String] = Map(...)`

I belive the issue is that `Meeting` and `MissingInformation` are not part of your `Status` ADT.